# trying to nest an if else statement for form validation

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation

I am trying to nest another if statement inside the following if statement for form validation. Basically I want the if statement to apply to all the fields (as it currently does) but then provide extra requirements for certain fields. the nested if statement is doing nothing right now. Ideally I would like to be able to have an extra parameter for the inputValidation function calls which I could set to true if I require that the field only accept non-numbers. But a nested if statement as I have written below which works would serve just as well!

```js
const firstName = document.getElementById('fname');
const lastName = document.getElementById('lname');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const fAddress = document.getElementById('first-line-address');
const city = document.getElementById('city');
const country = document.getElementById('country');
const postcode = document.getElementById('postcode');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

function inputValidation(element, greaterThan, lessThan) {
  element.addEventListener('input', function(element) {
    if (element.target.value.length >= greaterThan && element.target.value.length <= lessThan) {
      submitButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
      //        nested if statements isNaN
      if (element === 'firstName' || element === 'lastName' && isNaN(element.target.value)) {
        submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
      }
    } else {
      submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
    }
  })
}

inputValidation(firstName, 2, 15);
inputValidation(lastName, 4, 20);
inputValidation(email, 7, 40);
inputValidation(fAddress, 10, 40);
inputValidation(city, 3, 40);
inputValidation(postcode, 8, 8);
```

Comment: *"the nested if statement is doing nothing right now"* - This is a good opportunity to use a debugger and be more specific.  When the `if` condition executes, what are the exact runtime values of the variables being used?  What is the result of the condition?  What result was expected?  Why?  As part of your debugging you can even extract each component of that condition into their own variables and observe the specific results of each piece of the boolean logic.  Any time the code isn't doing what you expect, debug to find out more.

Comment: To add on to @David's comment, if you need help debugging, you'll need to provide those initial values and expected outcomes in the question. In this case, if you [edit] the question, you can provide HTML with the inputs having the values that should trigger the nested if but don't.

Answer (score 1):

Your `element` argument is [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), not a [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

Condition `element === 'firstName'` will never be true, beacuse you are comparing two different types: HTMLElement to string.

Try

```
if (element === firstName || element === lastName && isNaN(element.target.value)) {
    submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
}
```